# Merge Value Of Multiple Record based on similar criteria in Access/SQL/Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, vba

Currently I have a Table of Rows looked like this

[image: Table]

I would like to merge all Rows with same FlNo to a single Row, the data of merged row follow by these criteria:

- 'FlNo' remain the same
- 'Start' would be the earliest Date
- 'End' would be the lastest date
- 'Pattern' would represent the day of week, so it would be combination of all day of weeks that appeared in every rows (ie. if Row 1 have Pattern = "12347", Row 2 = "34567", combined Pattern would = "1234567", ie2: If Row1 = "357", Row2 = "357", combined Pattern would remain the same = "357"). This part has bothered me most as I haven't found the algorithm to solve it.
- 'AC_Name' would be the value which appeared most time for a FlNo (in this case would be 32)

So the Final Row would be

```
FlNo  |   Start     |   End         | Pattern  | AC_Name |  
 660  | 26/Mar/2017 |   28/Oct/2017 | 1234567  |    32   |
```

As the original Data is an Excel Spreadsheet so the solution should be provided based on Excel (VBA)/Access (VBA/SQL) environment. It could process in Excel first then Import to Access or Import to Access then process in there or half/half). Personally I would prefer to process in Access and SQL as there is about 13000s Rows of Data.

Please help me to find a solution to process this data. Thank you guys a lot.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Have a single column for each day of the week, filled with a flag (say "0" and "1") indicating whether the day is part of the "pattern".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your respond. Yes I could do that, but then how do I merge the data together?

Comment: It is an interesting question.Wish you had provided data in particlar manner instead of image.Second part of question is not clear.What is your actual database excel/access/sql server ?May be this is ideal scenario for SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have fixed the data, the query for all but `Ac_Name` would simply be:

```
select FINo, min(start), max(end),
       max(IsMonday), max(IsTuesday), . . .
from t
group by FINo;
```

Getting `Ac_Name` is tricky.  This should work:

```
select FINo, min(start), max(end),
       max(IsMonday), max(IsTuesday), . . .,
       (select top 1 ac_name
        from t as t2
        where t2.FINo = t.FINo
        group by ac_name
        order by count(*) desc, ac_name
       ) as ac_name
from t
group by FINo;
```

Comment: What if I also want to select 3 other fields, Blkt, STD, STA. I would like to choose the Max(Blkt) with STD and STA equivalent to it (Each blkt Have it own STD and STA). Thank you so much!

Comment: @TracNgon . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not as comments.  However, you might be able to repeat the subquery to get additional columns.

Answer (score 1):

once you have properly fixed  you data structure for you pattern column

you could use min(), max() and group by .. united  to  a selected  table with max for count

```
  select 
    t1.FlNo
,  min(t1.Start )
,  max( t1.End) 
, max(D1)
, max(D2)
, max(D3)
, max(D4)   
, max(D5)
, max(D6)
, max(D7)
, t2.AC_Name 
  from my_table t1
  INNER JOIN ( 

      select FlNo, AC_Name, max(my_count) from ( 
      select FlNo, AC_Name , count(*) AS  my_count
      from my_table
      group by FlNo, AC_Name ) t 
      GROUP BY lNo, AC_Name
      having my_count = max(my_count)
  ) t2  on t1.FlNo = t2.FlNo
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me (I only changed my_table to my table name, also added a comma after t1.FlNo on 1st line). The error says there is an error on Count(*) my_count

Comment: Also After I have new structure 7 columns for pattern, mamed: D1,D2,.... with value being 0 or 1. How do I also join them in as well?

Comment: I'm still receiving error `"Your query does not include the specified expression 'my_count = max(my_count)' as part of an aggregate function"`. I'm not yet fully understand the code, but I noticed for the 3rd Select group you put them as __t__ but haven't used it, is it on purpose?

Comment: Same error still appeared for some reason, maybe it would work in MySQL but not MSSQL? Thank you for your help anyway, really appreciate it!